# switchMap a Promise Observable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

environment:

- rxjs6
- es6

I write a function called "getStatus$" to mock an async promise, and turned it to an observable.

When I subscribe it,it works fine.

But I put it into a pipe, it doesn't work.

What's the problem?

How to fix it?

Thanks~

```js
const { from, interval } = rxjs
const { switchMap } = rxjs.operators

const getStatus$ = () => from(new Promise(res => {
 setTimeout(() => {
   res('zdl')
  }, 1000);
}));
// 1s
// 'first zdl'
// It works
getStatus$().subscribe(str => console.log('first', str));

// It doesn't work
// nothing output
interval(1000).pipe(
  switchMap(getStatus$)
).subscribe(str => console.log('second', str));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/rxjs/6.2.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks to [Fan Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8618350/fan-cheung), two ways:

```
interval(1000).pipe(
  mergeMap(getStatus$)
).subscribe(str => console.log('second', str));
// or
const getStatus$ = () => from(new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    res('zdl')
  }, 500);
}));
```

Comment: `switchmap` will cancel the inner observable if the source observable emits. i.e when interval emit `getsStatus$` get canceled, use `mergeMap` instead

Comment: That's the reason! Thank you very much~
`mergeMap` is ok, When I changed `setTimout` to 500ms(less than interval 1000ms) it also works.

Comment: Can you please put the answer as answer and not as an edit of the question :) ? Thank's.

Comment: Yes, of course~

Comment: Most of the time I wouldn't suggest use Promise combine with Observable as everything Promise can do, can also be achieved by Observable. Unless one of the existing 3rd party library is using unavoidable Promise interfaces.

Comment: In this code I just use Promise to mock a http request~
Usually when a promise is transfered to an observable, it can be handled by lot of operators as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Fan Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8618350/fan-cheung), two ways:

method 1, use `mergeMap` operator to replace `switchMap`:

```js
const { from, interval } = rxjs
const { mergeMap } = rxjs.operators

const getStatus$ = () => from(new Promise(res => {
 setTimeout(() => {
   res('zdl')
  }, 1000);
}));

interval(1000).pipe(
  mergeMap(getStatus$)
).subscribe(str => console.log('second', str));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/rxjs/6.2.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

method 2, make `getStatus$` time shorter than `interval`, I change it to 500ms:

```js
const { from, interval } = rxjs
const { switchMap } = rxjs.operators

const getStatus$ = () => from(new Promise(res => {
 setTimeout(() => {
   res('zdl')
  }, 500);
}));

interval(1000).pipe(
  switchMap(getStatus$)
).subscribe(str => console.log('second', str));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/rxjs/6.2.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```